# How to redirect the output of my program into a .txt file using Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I need to redirect the output of a function into a .txt file.
I'm using the function *printClassTree()* from the library *ontospy*.
The code of my program is very simple:

```
import ontospy
g = ontospy.Graph("/home/gabsbelini/Documentos/ontologiaTeste.owl")
g.printClassTree()
```

I've tried:

```
python myprogram.py > file.txt
```

But it does not work.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04
When I execute the command above it just creates the "file.txt" and shows the output in the terminal (I want that to be saved in file.txt)

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work" ? Also, do refer this answer for some variations: http://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

Comment: I wonder if `g.printClassTree()` is for some reason printing to *stderr* instead of *stdout* - Does `python myprogram.py 2> file.txt` work?

Comment: It also works Jon Clements =) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try tee:

```
python myprogram.py | tee file.txt
```

or from python

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as fh:
     fh.write(g.printClassTree())
```

EDIT
In case is going to `stderr` you can try:

python myprogram.py 2>&1 | tee file.txt

EDIT2

```
 with open('file.txt', 'w') as fh:
      fh.write(str(g.printClassTree()))
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it didn't work.
With the second one the file was created and an error was thrown "Typeerror: expected a character buffer object"
I googled that and was told to convert to string before writing into the file, 
changed to 

    fh.write(str(g.printClassTree())

and the output on the file was "None"

Will try your new advice, thanks a lot

Comment: Dude, THANK YOU VERY MUCH!
Was trying that for a long time!
It worked !!

Comment: comment left by Jon Clements will do it as well then, but YW.

Comment: (didn't upvote because I don't have the minimum reputation)